# Hover on one of multiple div and delay, then drop down the child div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know there is lots of similar question like this, I've been searching and tried for hours but no luck.

What I'm trying to do is easy,there is multiple block in my page like this
and the `.description` class will pop up when user hover on `.frame` element

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4">
        <div class="frame">
            <div class="description">
                <h3>Title</h3>
                <p>Description</p>
            </div>
        </div>        
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
        <div class="frame">
            <div class="description">
                <h3>T2</h3>
                <p>Description</p>
            </div>
        </div>        
    </div>
</div>
```

I think it's quite annoying when user swipe over the screen and every description gets triggered, so I tried to add a "delay condition" through `setTimeout()`, thus, only when user stop on one block for atleast 1sec, the description pops up

But it just don't go well and here's my
[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DennisKao/1esrLrfs/67/)

It's the best I can do, the delay function works, but it seems have two trigger on it.

**jQuery code:**

```
var timer;

$(document).ready(
    function(){
        $(".frame").hover(        
            function() {
                var descrip_in=$(".description",$(this))
                timer = setTimeout(function(){descrip_in.slideToggle();}, 1000);

            },     
            function() {       
                var descrip_out=$(".description",$(this))
                clearTimeout(timer);
                descrip_out.slideToggle(1000)
            }
        );    
    }
);
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem with it? What behaviour are you expecting to have?

Comment: i want the `.description` pop up only when user hover in `frame` over 1sec;
in the demo, it still got trigger when you swipe over it.(sorry for poor grammar)

Comment: @DennisKao by swipe you mean the mouse pointer stays in the frame and outside the frame..or you are testing it in a mobile phone for swipe?

Comment: not in mobile phone, i mean if mouse stay on `frame` less than 1sec, I don't want the `.description` pop up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, it was subtle.

By using slideToggle instead of slideDown and slideUp, you were toggling the popup on exit if you left the element before the timeout went off!

```
var timer;

$(document).ready(
    function(){
        $(".frame").hover(        
            function() {
                var descrip_in=$(".description",$(this))
                timer = setTimeout(function(){descrip_in.slideDown();}, 1000);

            },     
            function() {       
                var descrip_out=$(".description",$(this))
                clearTimeout(timer);
                descrip_out.slideUp(1000)
            }
        );    
    }
);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/1esrLrfs/71/

Comment: Thanks a lot!  but..how come?!!

Comment: If you were hovering on the element and exited before the timeout went off, you'd end up calling the toggleSlide once *while exiting*. And that was what triggered the popup, not the timeout somehow setting off anyhow. That's a common mistake with bi-stable logic like the toggle functions, to be safe you should always try to use the direct on and off functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can check in the handler out function that whether your element is displaying or not, then apply toggle function.

From your code

```
 var timer ,isToggle;
  $(document).ready(
    function(){
        $(".frame").hover(        
            function() {
                var descrip_in=$(".description",$(this))
                timer = setTimeout(function(){descrip_in.slideToggle();}, 1500);        
            },     
            function() {       
                var descrip_out=$(".description",$(this))
                clearTimeout(timer);
                if(descrip_out.css('display') !== 'none')
                descrip_out.slideToggle(1000)
            }
        );    
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The same can also used with `show` and `hide` functions too. The slideToggle function gets called even before you reach the timeout and it wont work.

You can see the [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/lakshman/2yt7zr98/)

```
$(function() {
    var timeoutId;
    $(".frame").hover( showDesc, hideDesc );
});

function showDesc(){
 var descrip_in=$(".description",$(this))
 timer = setTimeout(function(){descrip_in.show(200);}, 1000);
}

function hideDesc(){
    var descrip_out=$(".description",$(this))
    clearTimeout(timer);
    descrip_out.hide(300)
}
```

Comment: thanks dude, never thought that, and thanks for your correction, really.